# TVOS Resources List

Tags: apple-tv, tvos

Looking to the documentation and template examples of TVOS for the new Apple TV, I have seen there are badges where you can use a resource.
**Example:**

```
<badge src="resource://mpaa-pg" class="badge" />
<badge src="resource://button-play" />
<badge src="resource://cc" class="badge" />
```

Does someone know where can I find a list of all the available resources?
I can´t find it in the documentation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a list of some buttons but also badges : closed captions, common sense's labels, pg ratings... here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/57807#57807

also, (taken from part of the thread)

> As a work-around before having some documentation
>   you can find ressources (.png files) at this location :
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/System/Library/

Comment: Thank you very much Shirley!

Answer (score 0):

Available list of resources value can be found by below link..

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ResourceValues.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is still no documentation about the resources. What I was able to find out is that you can reference files form your `Assets.xcassets` file:

```
<img src="resource://LaunchImage"/>
```

you can as well reference images from `Assets.car` files form the

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

Using this [cartool](https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/cartool) I was able to list the contents of `TVMLKit.framework\Assets.car` and they are all usable like this:

```
<img src="resource://popover-chevron-up"/>
```